# Xamarin.Forms and binding for ElementName

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to bind my ListView Item to Command from my parent ViewModel. The problem is that I would like to add CommandParameter with current Item

Basically, in WPF i would do something like

```
<MyItem Command="{Binding ElementName=parent", Path=DataContext.MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

In Xamarin Forms ElementName is not working, so the way is to use BindingContext, but how I should use it (if one of my binding points to parent, second one to self)?

I have tried

```
<MyItem Command="{Binding BindingContext.RemoveCommand, Source={x:Reference parent}}" CommandParameter="{Binding }" />
```

But it does not work (seems it not changing Source).

I know, that with normal binding a way is to use `BindingContext="{x:Reference parent}"`, but it won't work in this example, because I need `Self` binding for CommandParameter

How can i do it?

Comment: Additionally, MyItem is a child of DataTemplate

Comment: It's not clear to me what are you trying to do. Can you give some context to your question? What are you trying to achieve in the UI?

Comment: Not sure if I can follow...wouldn't you simply have a `Parent` property on your binding context and call `RemoveCommand` on that? Like: `Command="{Binding Parent.RemoveCommand}"`? You don't want to call the command on the UI element (that's what `x:Reference` is for). The _sender_ of the command will be the current element, so no need to use a parameter here.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to execute a command on the parent node of your current node but pass the current node as a parameter. If that is the case, you can solve it like this:

Here's the model we bind to. It has a `Parent` property and it defines an `ICommand` (please note that all is C#6 code, so you'll need XS or VS2015!):

```
public class BindingClass
{
    public BindingClass (string title)
    {
        this.TestCommand = new TestCommandImpl (this);
        this.Title = title;
    }

    public string Title { get; }
    public ICommand TestCommand { get; }
    public BindingClass Parent { get; set; }
}
```

In the code behind, the binding context is set:

```
this.BindingContext = new BindingClass ("Bound Button") {
    Parent = new BindingClass ("Parent")
};
```

And in the XAML, we have a button that calls the command of the parent node and passes the current node as a parameter:

```
<Button
    x:Name="btnTest"
    Text="{Binding Title}"
    Command="{Binding Parent.TestCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```